# NoSuchFileException java

Tags: java, file, javafx

So I'm currently working on a java fx project and I am trying to get my program to read 2 txt files (name.txt) and (password.txt). When I run this in IntelliJ it works as intended but when I run the jar file in power shell I get this:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1787)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8879)
        at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:200)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3851)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1200(Scene.java:3579)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2588)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:390)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
        at com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1782)
        ... 47 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\ybald\details\name.txt
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:235)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:375)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:426)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Files.java:3272)
        at securenotes.user.User.getName(User.java:63)
        at securenotes.login.LogIn.checkLogin(LogIn.java:38)
        at securenotes.login.LogIn.logIn(LogIn.java:32)
        ... 59 more
```

the code that is supposed to tell where to look at the text files are this:

```java
    public String getName() throws IOException{
        return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("details/name.txt").toAbsolutePath()));
    }

    public String getPass() throws IOException{
        return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("details/password.txt").toAbsolutePath()));
    }
```

Also the .txt files are in the project folder

Comment: IntelliJ, and other IDEs, often look for files in other directories of your project, not just the ones relative to your .class/.jar files. Try putting the .jar file and the .txt files relative to each other as indicated by the methods.

Comment: `Paths.get("details/password.txt")` creates a _relative path_. You then convert it to an absolute path via `toAbsolutePath()`. The way relative paths are resolved to absolute paths is to resolve them against the working directory of the application. When you launch from IntelliJ the working directory is likely the project directory. If you don't use the same working directory when launching from the console then, unless you move `details/password.txt` to the new relative position, the resolved absolute file will not exist. The same reasoning applies to `details/name.txt`.

Comment: i resolved the issue with the terminal by switching from C: to D: but this app is meant to run on other devices. How can i make it so that jar file knows where to look at? The password and name txt files are stored in the same folder where i can find the jar file

Comment: That's one of the issues with using relative paths. It might be better to use a "known location" (e.g. `[user-home]/[app-folder]/...`). Or, as it's not necessarily too difficult to determine what platform you're on, put application data in platform-specific places (e.g. Windows uses the local/roaming "AppData" folder, the locations of which can be gotten from environment variables, at least on Windows 10).

Comment: Are the contents of the files going to change after the application is deployed to the individual computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your stacktrace, I see that the file in question is  “C:\Users\ybald\details\name.txt”. If it’s not found, it’s probably not there, and so I guess you used a relative path. The path is relative to the directory your started the jvm in. Your IDE uses another directory than you do when you start your program unfroh the shell.

Use an absolute path, and it will work. You can use `dir.resolve(filename)` to turn your relative path into an absolute one.

Comment: C:\Users\ybald\details\name.txt does not have the file but that's because it shouldn't anyway. the path to the file should be "D:\JavaPrograms\SecureNotes\details" but for some reason, it won't look for it there and aim not using absolute path already? "Paths.get("details/name.txt").toAbsolutePath()"

also, i am running my program's jar file on the shell

Comment: @Ghozti but `"details/name.txt"` sure is not an absolute path - is is relative to the working directory (where started? `C:\Users\ybald`)

Comment: You have to use an absolute path for dir of course.

Comment: but .toAbsolutePath() is supposed to return the absolute path. And it works on the IDE once again but when i build my project to a jar file it looks for the file in C:\Users\ybald when it should not even do that

Comment: Yes, and it does return the absolute path of the file you get when resolving your relative path from the directory that you were in when you started your program. It’s like finding the way to the train station: „take the second street to the left, then it’s the third house to your right“ does only work when you are located at the correct starting point. What you need is Paths.get(“C:/<put the correct path here>”).resolve(“details/name.txt”).

Comment: ok that works for me but what if this app runs on another machine? it won't have the same path

Comment: If the file is part of your App, put it on the class path and use Class.getRessource().